# Shortest path tree claim (Graph)

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, graphing, claims

Claim: If all the edges weights in a graph are distinct, then there is a unique shortest path tree. Either give a convincing argument that the claim is true or give a counterexample.

Comment: What's kind of graph are you using?( I assume you are using A* grid graph? )

Comment: Could you expand on "if all edge weights are distinct".

Comment: It is a MST (Minimum Spanning Tree), that is why all of the edges are distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have MST then there is a unique path from every two vertices which makes the shortest path tree senseless. I assume you meant the result is a MST. However, this is not true. Shortest path trees are different from minimum spanning trees for the same graph and even for the same root. *Shortest Path tree rooted on vertex `v`*  is usually the result of applying Dijkstra's algorithm over `v`.

In general, uniqueness for trees over graphs is hard to be believed in unless strict requirements were given (like the new weights equal old ones +1).  @rici gave a counterexample with a polytree structure. Here is another counterexample for undirected graphs. Both trees are shortest path trees rooted at `A`.  Note that:

- While both are shortest path trees, their total cost differ.
- Both are spanning trees but neither one of them is a minimum.

[image: two shortest path trees over vertex A]

Comment: I guess you have by mistake swapped the weights of edges EC and BC. In middle graph, path from A to C has total weight 4+3=7. In rightmost graph, path from A to C has total weight 5+6=11. Making weight(EC)=2 and weight(BC)=6 seems to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question, correctly:

[image: Counterexample]